# Thymeleaf rendering issue

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using following code to get a `<label>` with a `<option>` list.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sort" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Students
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select class="form-control" name="sort" id="sort">
                <option th:each="student : ${students}"
                        th:value="${student.status}"
                        th:text="${student.status}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But in the browser I'm getting only following html, for this code snipet.

```html
<div class="row"></div>
```

I'm using spring MVC with Thymeleaf.

How can I figure out this?

Comment: did you remember to recompile your resources? with ctrl+F9 you can achieve it

Comment: @cralfaro, I removed all the files in the build folder and compiled again. No changes.

Comment: also you need to add the dependecy  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
  </dependency>